# jetpack compose exoplayer change url on run time

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-videoview, android-jetpack, exoplayer

I'm using kotlin language with jetpack compose for android app
I create main activity with exoplayer library to show video and some buttons
every button have url video
i want when i click any button on run time show the exactly video it have by exoplayer library

Answer (score 0):

Well I have fixed this by using:

```
    viewModel.scope.launch {
         exoPlayer.setMediaItem(MediaItem.fromUri("videoUrl"))
    }
```

and my viewModel.scope is set by:

```
viewModel.scope = rememberCoroutineScope()
```

Hope this helps